# Dell DImension C521 won't automatically connect to a wired network

Tags: 10.10, networking, wireless

My parents were having continuous trouble with Windows Vista. The problem was that Vista refused to connect to the wired network set up for them, and if it did it would only last for a day or two and then quit. Finally yesterday it quit connecting completely no matter what I did, so I took the initiative to install Ubuntu onto their computer.

(Needless to say, they love it since I installed a Mac OSX theme and Docky :].)

The wired network connects just fine but I have to manually connect to it via the launcher bar up top every time it boots up. This wouldn't bug me if it was my computer but I don't want my parent's to have to remember how to connect each time, any help?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu used to have a hard-coded default state for wired ethernet which has vanished from recent releases in favour of letting Network Manager, erm, manage the network.

You can usurp Network Manager, restoring the old behaviour by running `sudoedit /etc/network/interfaces` and appending:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

That assumes your network adapter lives at `eth0` (`ifconfig -a` can tell you if this is the case).

Save and restart. If the network springs into life, hooray. If it doesn't and/or Network Manager's applet starts popping veins, revert the edit and find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a start up script like this:

1) Create a file

```
gedit ~/.scripttoconnect.sh
```

2) Paste this into the file

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# to connect after login
#
sleep 5 && nmcli con up id 'name_of_connection'
```

3) Save the file

4) Add permission to execute

```
 sudo chmod +x ~/.scripttoconnect.sh
```

5) Add to startup applications

```
gnome-session-properties
```

Enjoy ;-)